# iСloud upload files on Macbook very slowly

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, catalina

I wanted to turn off the synchronization of some documents in iCloud, in the settings I turned off the necessary checkbox, after which started a long download, which loads the battery. Im working with node_modules, so there are so many files.

How can I speed up this loading?

Note: Loading bar is not moving. Only the number of files decreases. (125 250, after 10 sec => 125 100)

[image]

Comment: you can download those documents via https://privacy.apple.com & then delete them from cloud. then turn off the sync for those folders.

Comment: Thank you. This upload ended 10-15 minutes ago without any extra things, I only had to wait